Lifecycle of a CoroutineScope
I am trying to understand runBlocking and CoroutineScope better.
I wrote the following code. serviceCall1 and etc are suspend functions returning some integer.
fun testFun1() {
        val output = compParallel(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO))
        println("output is $output")
}
    
fun compParallel(scope: CoroutineScope) : Int {
        val f1 = listOf<suspend (Long) -> Int>(::serviceCall1, ::serviceCall2, ::serviceCall3, ::serviceCall4)
        return runBlocking(scope.coroutineContext) {
            launch {
                try {
                    delay(5000)
                    println("I am late")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("I am cancelled")
                } finally {
                    println("I am finalled")
                }
            }
            f1.mapIndexed {
                idx, a -> scope.async {
                    a(idx.toLong())
                }
            }.awaitAll().sum()
        }
}

When I run it,
I am late
I am finalled

Are printed.
However, if I change
        launch {
            try {
                delay(5000)
                println("I am late")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("I am cancelled")
            } finally {
                println("I am finalled")
            }
        }

to
        scope.launch {
            try {
                delay(5000)
                println("I am late")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("I am cancelled")
            } finally {
                println("I am finalled")
            }
        }

those two lines do not get printed.
My understanding is that once testFun1() finished running and the CoroutineScope created by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) is out of scope, it will cancel all jobs and thus those two lines should be printed.
Can someone help explain why the output is the way it is?

Your example is pretty confusing, it is hard to answer, I don't know where to start. These two lines are not printed most probably because in the second example you launch the code in the background, but you progress further with the code and the whole application probably finishes before 5s. In the first example you wait for it. You say something about CoroutineScope being out of scope, but coroutine scopes never cancel anything by themselves - we have to cancel them explicitly. If we don't, they are running forever.

Also, passing a coroutine context of an existing scope to a coroutine builder function (runBlocking) is a serious code smell to me, and I expect some really strange and hard to debug behavior when doing this.

In the first scenario where
I am late
I am finalled

are printed is because runBlocking waits for all its children coroutine to complete before exiting.
In the second scenario where
I am late
I am finalled

are printed is because scope.launch is used and the created coroutine is NOT a coroutine inside runBlocking's coroutineScope. runBlocking does not care about its status and exits before scope.launch coroutine completes.
